# Fastest way to parse an arbitrarily large string with a known format (including pulling out substrings)

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, parsing

This is possibly a few different things rolled into one, because the data being parsed has multiple things that need to be done with it to get the final data structure. The format I'm working with is as follows:

```
2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %a - title 1
#tag1 @tag2 #tag3
%meta{data}
%meta2{data1;data2}
    contents1
    contents2

2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %b - title 2
#tag
%meta{data}
    contents3
    contents4
```

There is a full date (including time zone), a separator, another full date (with time zone), a separator, an id (also in a specific format), a separator, a title with arbitrary length and can include unicode, multiple pieces of metadata on separate lines (such as tags), and finally text content of arbitrary length with an arbitrary number of lines using spaces to know when we start/finish the text content. In order to parse this I'm going over every `.codePointAt()` with a simple index up to `.length` of the string. I do things like skip whitespace until I find content, use character math to get ints for things like the dates as fast as possible (`s.codePointAt(i) - '0'.charCodeAt(0)`, though caching the ascii number value of 0), take `.substring()`s, use the JS version of joda-time to get zoned date times, validate the input to make sure it's in the correct format (e.g.: check for the separators, make sure we get a number at each code point when parsing an int), etc.

But even with doing my best to get the best performance out of my current parser, it's still a lot slower than a parser I wrote in Java. I know you can get JS performance that is extremely high, and I'm certain that I can get more performance than what I'm currently getting. But I don't know enough about JS to know what techniques I can use to get the best performance. Do I need to make a library wrapping around string values to create "substrings" that don't call `.substring` because it's going to be higher performance because it won't copy string data like `.substring` would? Is there a faster way to iterate over/access every character in the string? Can dates be created with timezone faster? etc.

I'm currently reading the text from a file on the filesystem with nodejs, so if there's going to be a technique available to node that might not be available to browser-based JS, let me know.

EDIT: The output I'm currently getting from this is two entries, which would look approximately like the following JS object:

```js
[
  {
    id: "a",
    // NOTE: My actual output uses joda-time to get a ZonedDateTime
    // that uses the "America/New_York" part to ensure the resulting
    // dates are in that time zone and not assuming it's always local
    // time or UTC or something.
    created: new Date(2020, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    updated: new Date(2020, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    title: "title 1",
    tags: ["#tag1", "@tag2", "#tag3"],
    metadata: [
      {name: "meta", data: ["data"]},
      {name: "meta2", data: ["data1", "data2"]}
    ],
    content: [
      "contents1",
      "contents2"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "b",
    created: new Date(2020, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    updated: new Date(2020, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    title: "title 2",
    tags: ["#tag"],
    metadata: [
      {name: "meta", data: ["data"]}
    ],
    content: [
      "contents3",
      "contents4"
    ]
  }
]
```

ALSO: Keep in mind this file could be arbitrarily large. For example, a test file I work with to check how well my JS code is performing is 24MB large and it can parse that in ~260 milliseconds (from a purely in memory string), while my Java code can parse a 21MB test file in ~120 milliseconds (while reading it from a file in a loop, so it'll be cached, but it's still higher overhead per operation). (both time measurements are taken over multiple iterations to ensure the JIT has time to warm up and optimize code)

EDIT EDIT: Updated performance measurements. I thought the JS code was a larger gap away from the Java code than it is, but it's still twice as slow and I'd like to know if there's a way to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression match could do this pretty fast. If, like in your example, the input file doesn't have lines that *start* with numbers other than dates, you can `.split` by the delimiter `^(?=\d)` - the start of a line followed by a digit:

```js
const text = `2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %id - title
#tag
%meta{data}
    contents1
    contents2
2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %id - title
#tag
%meta{data}
    contents1
    contents2`;
const parts = text.split(/^(?=\d)/m);
console.log(parts);
```

The regular expression could be made more precise if needed, but more precision will likely involve a more complicated pattern, which could slow things down.

If you want to extract the sub-contents of each part as well, you could use `matchAll`:

```js
const text = `2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %a - title 1
#tag1 @tag2 #tag3
%meta{data}
%meta2{data1;data2}
    contents1
    contents2

2020-01-01 01:01:01 America/New_York -- 2020-02-02 02:02:02 America/New_York %b - title 2
#tag
%meta{data}
    contents3
    contents4`;
for (const match of text.matchAll(/(^\d.+)\n#(.+)\n(.+(?:\n%.+)*)((?:\n .*)+)/gm)) {
  const dates = match[1].match(/\d\S+ \S+ \S+/g);
  console.log('Dates:', dates);
  const tags = match[2].split(' ');
  console.log('Tag:', tags);
  const meta = match[3].split('\n');
  console.log('Meta:', meta);
  const content = match[4].slice(1).split('\n').map(s => s.slice(4));
  console.log('Content:', content);
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/IDxylR/1

`(^\d.+)` - Match and capture the date line (which starts with a digit)

`\n#` - Match and capture what comes before a tag

`(.+)` - Match the tag

`(.+(?:\n%.+)*)` - Match and capture the meta lines that start with `%` right after a newline and span the whole line

`\n.+` - Match what comes before the contents

`((?:\n .*)+)` - Match the contents (a newline, followed by a space, repeated)

Comment: Ah, that's my fault for not saying there can potentially be newlines between the entries. And I have to read each portion of each entry into a data structure. e.g.: the two dates, the title, etc. I'm not just using each entry as a raw string. EDIT: If there's a way I can make that clearer in the question, let me know.

Comment: I added a regex that looks to do what you want. If that doesn't work, please include in the question a realistic example of the input.

Comment: Added a more fleshed out input as well an approximation of the expected output, as well as some performance numbers.

Comment: Furthermore, the regexp will probably be faster than the time it took to read the row.